# ASP.NET - why would database file suddenly not be able to be found?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-ce

I am building an ASP.NET application using Microsoft SQL Server CE that needs to run a process for 24 hours at a time.  Yesterday I started an overnight test.  At about 2:30 AM it threw the following exception:

> The database file cannot be found. Check the path to the database. [ Data Source = ]

Here is the code snippet that was running.  It is a helper library that I use for data access:

```
public class DataHelper
{
  private string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnString"].ConnectionString;
  public void ExecuteNonQuery(string SQL)
  {
    using (SqlCeConnection _conn = new SqlCeConnection(_connectionString))
    {
      _conn.Open();
      using(SqlCeCommand _cmd = new SqlCeCommand(SQL, _conn))
      {
        _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then I have this in my web.config

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnString" connectionString="data source=|DataDirectory|\myDB.sdf"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

For my test I am running the ASP.NET application using the Visual Studio development web server (not IIS).  The application ran fine for a little over 12 hours.  Then all of a sudden it threw the above exception.  Any ideas why all of a sudden it wouldn't be able to find the database?  My first thought was that the VS development web server recycled the app pool or something and now the system lost the connection string.

Comment: I have to ask, why would you write an ASP.NET application that's supposed to run a process for 24 hours?  That's a task much more suitable to either a Windows Service, Console application, or WinForms application.  ASP.NET isn't designed for such things, and you can expect to have aberrant behavior.  IIS resetting, the app pool resetting, etc.  There are just too many unpredictable things to deal with that aren't a factor in the other application types.  Even when running in Cassini (The Visual Studio web server) rather than IIS, you can expect problems with a long-running process.

Comment: I sort of inherited this and the architecture decisions had already been made.  We are already planning a version 2 with a different architecture using exactly what you have mentioned.  However for now I have to do my best to get this working.

Comment: I hope someone is able to answer your quesiton, but I strongly suspect  that the answer is related to the inherent issues with ASP.NET and long-running processes, and that the only answer will be to break out the long-running process into a separate app.  Thankfully, porting asp.net code to a OCnsole app isn't too difficult, but I do hope you find an easier answer.  Good luck!  (Meant sincerely, not sarcastically).

Comment: Don't know if this would help, but it might be worth a try to remove the |DataDirectory| and replace it with the full path. Maybe that |DataDirectory| variable is getting lost somehow.

Comment: Yes I am already looking at breaking out the code to a Windows Service.  The only thing I don't really understand is how to communicate back and forth between the main ASP.NET application and the Windows Service.  My first thought is to use the database as a go-between.  But there has to be a better way.  I appreciate the help as I am trying something I have never done before.

Comment: With a Windows service, you can expose a WCF endpoint and have your other application talk to that service. The database idea might be easier, but having a service would definitely give you the ability to do more stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is really an answer to the original question or not, but I ended up splitting out the guts of the long running application in to a WCF service hosted in a Windows Service.  Now I am not having the original issue that I was having.